# cannot resolve URL in PHP

Tags: php, url, curl, google-api

When I make a request with cURL gives error "cannot resolve host URL". Should I encode URL? After I encoded Google API URL, it still gives error.

https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/contactGroups/batchGet

```
GET https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups:batchGet
```

Where is the problem?

```
    <?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups:batchGet",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Cache-Control: no-cache"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $response;
}
```

Comment: Try changing `:` into `%3A`

Comment: I did encoding all chars. But on centos7 still gives error. On Windows 10 it is OK. I feel weird.

Comment: I used Postman to make a request on Windows. I used TCP sniffer to extract URL. On Windows working URL is `http://localhost:9000/?properties=%7B%22annotators%22%3A%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Clemma%22%7D&pipelineLanguage=en` I found. Then I use it on Linux, URL ran successfully. I noticed some characters were not transformed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything wrong with the code, and I tested it and it worked fine.

I guess it's some issue with the DNS that can't resolve the host.

Comment: Centos 7 I use and cURL gives error. I tested on my Windows 10 is OK. Is there any difference between Apache server on Centos7 vs WAMP on Windows10?

Comment: What do you get when run curl from terminal in CentOS ? `curl https://people.googleapis.com/v1/contactGroups:batchGet`

Comment: @lemonsoft then the issue is not the code. Check your internet connection. Try to ping 8.8.8.8, if you are able to ping then the issue is your DNS server. You can check your DNS using `nmcli dev show | grep -i 'dns'`

Comment: I used Postman to make a request on Windows. I used TCP sniffer to extract URL. On Windows working URL is `http://localhost:9000/?properties=%7B%22annotators%22%3A%22tokenize%2Cssplit%2Clemma%22%7D&pipelineLanguage=en` I found. Then I use it on Linux, URL ran successfully. I noticed some characters were not transformed.